# Excel Formula Formatting

Tags: excel

I have an average formula in excel such as =AVERAGE(A2:A204) and I want to copy this exact formula down the whole column. When I drag it or double click it, it increments the 204 to 205 and so on. Is there a quick and easy way that I can copy the same formula down the row so that all 203 row have the formula =AVERAGE(A2:A204)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the references absolute with the `$`

```
=AVERAGE($A$2:$A$204)
```

The `$` before the `A` makes the column Absolute so as the formula is copied/dragged across the columns it will not change.

The `$` before the row number makes the row Absolute so as the formula is copied/dragged down or up the rows it will not change.

You can make part of the reference absolute.

If you want to anchor the `A2` and have the `A204` change as it is dragged/Copied down:

```
=AVERAGE($A$2:$A204)
```

Now the only number that will change is the `204` while the `2` remains steady.